# AdView Causing Chrome Crash?

Tags: android, admob

I have an adview in one of my activitites.  When I go to this activity, I get a dialog on the emulator telling me Chrome has stopped and the ad doesn't show anything.

I've checked over the code itself and I'm fairly sure it matches what it should -

**Activity.xml**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**Activity.java**

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Here is the **logcat** -

```
09-08 09:26:47.779 5777-5777/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x872ca5e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
09-08 09:26:47.783 5777-5777/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x872ca5e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x8379e7b0)
09-08 09:26:47.784 5892-5892/? E/asset: setgid: Operation not permitted
09-08 09:26:47.795 5878-5878/? W/ResourceType: Entry identifier 0xc is larger than entry count 0x8
09-08 09:26:47.795 5878-5878/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-08 09:26:47.795 5878-5878/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0, PID: 5878
                                                 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Array resource ID #0x7f03000c
                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.obtainTypedArray(Resources.java:617)
                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.preloadFonts(Resources.java:379)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5815)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.WebViewZygoteInit.main(WebViewZygoteInit.java:121)
09-08 09:26:47.799 1584-1600/? I/ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.androidandyuk.autobuddy u0
09-08 09:26:47.825 1357-1357/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4096
09-08 09:26:47.826 1584-2280/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-08 09:26:47.826 1584-2280/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
09-08 09:26:47.826 1584-2280/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
09-08 09:26:47.826 1584-2280/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
09-08 09:26:47.842 1357-1357/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4096
09-08 09:26:47.842 1584-2280/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa44a4be0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
09-08 09:26:47.848 1357-1357/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4096
09-08 09:26:47.849 1584-2280/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa44a4be0: ver 2 0 (tinfo
```

On my Pixel XL, it doesn't crash, but no ad is shown, so I guess something isn't right?

Comment: that's not your fault

Comment: i think this is a problem of emulator

Comment: Ok, thanks, but then no ads seem to show on my phone?  Is that a separate issue then?

Comment: when did you create your admob account and admob app id?

Comment: Wow, hmm.  Can't be sure if I made admob account when I started programming, which would be around 5 months ago.  Might be way back, like a couple of years though.  The app id I checked.  I would have made that 3 or 4 months back when I started the app.

Comment: Okay, I've been an idiot.  I google'd instructions to check my banner ad id, and it took my to the app ID.  I've but the banner ad ID back into strings.xml and it crashes Chrome on my Pixel too. I've just got a fresh Firebase json config, but that's not helped.

Comment: I've just tried it on the emulator with API 21 and it works fine...

Comment: I think you shout post your comment as an answer

Comment: For me just to check, the one that it looks to be a bug in API 26 as it works on lower API's?  Thanks.

Comment: Admob rely on google play services may be your emulator doesn't have it!

Answer (score 7):

We had the same crash in our app. A temporary solution was to disable the use of the **preloaded_fonts** tag in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: This worked for me. So no downloadable fonts for me if I have web views on my app :(

Comment: I thinks is caused by this issue, please star it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68976052

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug in Android 8.0 Oreo at present as this does not happen in earlier API's.